# C# Composite pattern and Database Access

Tags: c#, composite

Suppose I have a composite class `PharmaProduct`(which represents the product hierarchy of a pharmaceutical company) and a database table for it. I have thought two ways to load the data into a `PharmaProduct` object.

(1) Construct the entire object-tree when an object is instantiated. Make changes to the tree and persist those changes by applying recursive loop to the tree (This is actually the way C# `DataSet` works).

(2) Load a node. Load other nodes only if

```
PharmaProduct GetParent()
```

or,

```
List<PharmaProduct> GetChldren()
```

are called (which actually do the direct database access). Make change to the node. Only save that node.

This type of tables may have a thousand entries, depending on how many types of items a pharmaceutical company manufactures. So in that case, the 1st approach will be too clumsy (and also memory consuming) I think.

How should I actually do the database access in case of any Composite Pattern problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `Proxy` pattern. Using it, you would put `PharmaProductProxy` objects in the tree that have the same interface as `PharmaProduct`, but lazy load themselves when they are accessed.

Comment: Then this turns out to be a CompositeProxy pattern. Is this the case?

Comment: Note that depending on the database access technology, lazy loading comes with the product. Take e.g. NHibernate - make your "GetChildren" virtual, returning IList<PharmaProduct> and you should get a lazy loaded proxy straight away.

Comment: @JMSA, patterns frequently work together -- I've never heard it called that, but if someone did, I'd know what they meant. Usually you'd just say "I'm using Composite with Proxy to lazy load the parts"